# Reading images from directory

Tags: android

I am trying to load all the images from a directory in a specified path. Using the if statement to check for the path been called isn't giving out any error and there is no result been displayed also. Wouldn't mind getting to know where i am getting this code of mine wrong.

```
public class Edit extends Activity {

    // File representing the folder that you select using a FileChooser
    static final File dir = new File("/data/data/faceemoji.alexcz.yourfaceemoji/app_imageDir/");

    // array of supported extensions (use a List if you prefer)
    static final String[] EXTENSIONS = new String[]{
            "png" // and other formats you need
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

        Log.d("loadfilepath", dir.getAbsolutePath());
        if (dir.isDirectory()) { // make sure it's a directory
            System.out.println("yes");
            for (File f : dir.listFiles(IMAGE_FILTER)) {

                Log.d("fak", "file found");
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
                ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
                myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                linearLayout.addView(myImage);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_edit, menu);
        return true;
    }

    static final FilenameFilter IMAGE_FILTER = new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(final File dir, final String name) {
            for (String ext : EXTENSIONS) {
                if (name.endsWith("." + ext)) {
                    return (true);
                }
            }
            return (false);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/select-and-share-multiple-images/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Context.getFilesDir()` for internal storage and `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for external storage, for using this last one you have to add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` if you also want to write files.

In your case I guess you should do it like this:

```
static final File dir = new File(Context.getFilesDir()+"/app_imageDir/");
```

Even thoug put a Log to check that the directory is right